# apt-get update removes ROS melodic while installing ROS2 eloquent on Docker image

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, updates, docker

I am trying to install ROS2 and ROS in a Docker image.

The setup I have is as follow:

1. I have a ROS melodic image based on nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-base:r32.4.4, here I installed ROS melodic as in the guide [here](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu).
2. On the above image I am creating a layer with ROS2. In order to do so I am following the ROS2 installation guide [here](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Eloquent/Linux-Install-Debians/).

Anyway when I build the ROS2 image, I see the log of apt update that says that it is going to remove ROS melodic packages. I don't really understand why...

Do you know what could be the problem?
How can I avoid apt update uninstalling melodic (and why is this happening)?

Comment: Likely ROS and ROS2 use a lot of the same library installation paths, or having the two coinstalled breaks things.  It's possible you can only have one or the other installed and not both simultaneously.

Comment: They can stay together, the packages have different names ros-melodic* and ros-eloquent* (I installed manually ros2 inside the container and it works...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution but a weird trick. Instead of installing melodic and then eloquent, I did the inverse and it worked...
Now I have a Docker image with both ROS1 and ROS2